Java delete node from linked list and to store the removed node in a stack
How do i effeciently store the deleted value from linklist into a stack. And after storing i want to perform the undo operation on it in order to get the deleted node from the stack back into the linklist from where i removed it.
package DataStructure.LinkedListPractise;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class practiseLinkedList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List newList = new ArrayList();
        newList.add(32);
        newList.add(388);
        newList.add(129);


        for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(newList.get(i));
        }
        newList.remove(1);
        System.out.println();
    }
}


This is a 'please write my whole app' / 'please do my homework for me' style question; SO is not that kind of website.

So why remove it from the linked list at all?

You keep a track of another list of the removed index and value, then you can reapply them in order:
   public record Node(int index, int value){};
    
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        List newList = new ArrayList();
        newList.add(32);
        newList.add(388);
        newList.add(129);
        System.out.println("Full list: " + newList);
    
        List<Node> history = new ArrayList();
        history.add(0, new Node(1, (int) newList.remove(1)));
        System.out.println("Remove: 388 " + newList);
        history.add(0, new Node(1, (int) newList.remove(0)));
        System.out.println("Remove: 32 " + newList);
        
        Node lastItem = history.remove(0);
        newList.add(lastItem.index, lastItem.value);
        System.out.println("Return: 32 " + newList);
        
        lastItem = history.remove(0);
        newList.add(lastItem.index, lastItem.value);
        System.out.println("Return: 388 " + newList);
    }

Full list: [32, 388, 129]
Remove: 388 [32, 129]
Remove: 32 [129]
Return: 32 [32, 129]
Return: 388 [32, 388, 129]


I do not fully understand the purpose of the two dimensional arrays, but this is certainly a: +1

The two dimensional array is just to simplify the answer, but sure it is better to be replaced by a custom object like static class Node {int index; int value;} or record  Node(int index, int value) or Pair/Tuple instead of another array

so you store position in the original list and value of the removed item of the original list? ic...

yes, you need to track the index you removed and the object you removed to be able to undo this operation
